# THttpClient is not closing connection in Delphi

Tags: delphi, tcp, delphi-10.2-tokyo, sysinternals

My software includes the function below for posting to URL. I'm using Sysinternals TCPView to see the connection. The connection is not closing after posting to URL. How should I change the code for immediate connection close?

```
function PostURL(const AURL: string; Parameters: TStrings): string;
var
  HttpClient: THttpClient;
  HttpResponse: IHttpResponse;
begin
  HttpClient := THTTPClient.Create;
  try
    HttpClient.ConnectionTimeout:=3000;
    HttpClient.ResponseTimeout:=3000;
    HttpResponse := HttpClient.Post(AURL, Parameters, nil, TEncoding.UTF8);
    Result := HttpResponse.ContentAsString();
  finally
    HttpClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I do not find a Disconnect method. If I were you, I would use a well established library like Indy (use TIdHttp)... Tokyo comes with Indy components so you have it already.

Comment: Indy can not connect to https web sites on some computers.

Comment: Sure it can ;) Best is to distribute openssl dlls with your application.

Comment: What connection state does TCPView show?

Comment: I would expect `THTTPClient` to disconnect when it is destroyed. If it is not, file a bug report with Embarcadero

Comment: `"Indy can not connect to https web sites on some computers."` That is nonsense. If you have a problem implementing that, don't just give up - try to understand what you're doing wrong, and address it. Indy is perfectly capable of HTTPS. You just have to set it up as desired.

Comment: @JerryDodge and as whosrdaddy said, ensure the libraries are distributed with the app.

Comment: @mjn42 Established.

Comment: I dont prefer distributing the openssl libraries. I stick to THttpClient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about the following

```
 HttpClient.SetRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
```

Comment: Error: Undeclared identifier: 'SetRequestHeader'

Comment: Hooray! This one works! HttpClient.CustomHeaders['Connection']:='close';

Comment: cool, yes I was using winhttp hence the syntax difference but you figured out :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a feature of WinHttp, it keeps TCP connections alive for some time to reuse them faster, you can disable it by disabling this option in request.

```
OptionValue := WINHTTP_DISABLE_KEEP_ALIVE;
WinHttpSetOption(RequestHandle, WINHTTP_OPTION_DISABLE_FEATURE, @OptionValue, sizeof(OptionValue));
```

But there is no easy way to set this option in Delphi `THttpClient`, to do it you'll have to copy `System.Net.HttpClient.Win.pas` and `System.Net.HttpClient.pas` to your project and modify `System.Net.HttpClient.Win.pas` to add this code